# CSS3: repeating-linear-gradient

Tags: css, css3, градиент

Я сделала следующий гардиент для фона:

[image: Градиент1]

Возможно ли изменить направление красно-черного градиента полосок, чтобы, например, градиент имел направление `to bottom` (красный цвет был вверху, а черный внизу на полосках)?

Примерно так:

[image: Градиент2]

```css
.bg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #d43434 0px, #000 20px, transparent 20px, transparent 40px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #04bcef 0%, #ed8200 53%, #ed8200 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать тут JS — совсем крайний случай, так как от этого будет сильно страдать производительность и сопровождаемость вашего кода.

Проблема данного градиента, который надо повернуть, в том, что между повторениями самого градиента нужны пробелы и нет способа CSS, чтобы их добавить.

Поэтому сделаем картинку с помощью SVG: прямоугольник, который занимает 50% ширины картинки с нужным нам градиентом.

```css
svg {
  /* бесконечная серая тень чтобы выделить саму картинку */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" >
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#d43434"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#000"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect width="50%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)"  />
</svg>
```

Далее либо сохраним эту картинку и используем ссылку на неё (предпочтительно), либо зашифруем её (к примеру, с помощью этого [сервиса](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)) для использования в CSS:

```css
.bg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: 
    url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3ClinearGradient id='gradient' gradientUnits='objectBoundingBox' x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='1' %3E%3Cstop offset='0' style='stop-color:%23d43434'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' style='stop-color:%23000'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Crect width='50%25' height='100%25' fill='url%28%23gradient%29' /%3E%3C/svg%3E") 0 0 / 40px 100% round,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #04bcef 0%, #ed8200 53%, #ed8200 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

В примере выше данному SVG установлен `background-size: 40px 100%` и `background-repeat: repeat-x`.

Answer (score 1):

`180deg` — могли бы и сами циферки поправить

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #d43434 0px, #000 20px, transparent 20px, transparent 40px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #04bcef 0%, #ed8200 53%, #ed8200 100%);
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно изменить не направление полос, а направление градиента на полосках. Полоски должны оставаться вертикальными. Добавила в описание изображение результата.

Comment: тогда надо переделовать ... в этом случае так не получится , но можно наложить ещё один градиент ...под низ - утром если ответ ни кто не даст - сделаю

Answer (score 1):

Если мы не можем вывести стандартно градиент по каким то причинам, то сделаем  через циклы, что бы не городить эти `span`. Я их вывел в цикле на JS, ну а стилизовал в CSS. Смотрите:

```js
var Temp = document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML;
for (var n = 1; n <= 29; n++) {
  Temp += "<span></span>";
  document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = Temp;
}
```

```css
.item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.item span {
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100vh;
}

span:nth-child(odd) {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(162, 40, 40, .8), #000);
}

span:nth-child(even) {
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue 0%, green 30%, orange 70%);
}
```

```html
<div id="elem" class="item"></div>
```